Old Scifi movie intelligent ants
I saw a movie around 10 years ago. it took place in a remote desert area. A mineral company sent some employees out to an outpost.  People started disappearing  and when they were found, all their bones were gone.  It turned out that a colony of intelligent ants was using human bones to build a structure so that groups of ants could quickly use them to move long distances. The end revealed a hugh cpu made by connecting  ants into an intelligent synapse network.  The mmovie may have had a 1 word voodoo sounding name.  It may have been an Australian or English movie.  I would like to know the movie name so I could watch it again.

You saw it 10 years ago, but did it seem like a 2005 movie, or older? English? American or UK,  etc?

I was going to say "Them", but that's much older, and doesn't match all your plot points.

The Bone Snatcher is from the right time period and features a remote outpost under siege from a colony of intelligent ants. The ants form up on a skeleton and animate it to walk around. 




It might be Phase IV
Some details ring true - e.g. the desert setting. There were computers involved as well, so I'm not sure if that's what you're remembering as the "huge CPU".



